# User Authentication or validation

Tags: hibernate, jsp, servlets, web-applications, vs-web-application-project

I'm developing a web application using JSP, servlet and hibernate. while developing I stuck at user validation. Initially, I was setting some attributes in session and checking it on every next JSP page, but as the number of JSP's are increased it becomes a problem for me. I just want a common way for whole the application so that the user can not access any resource without login.

Answer (score 1):

**`javax.servlet.Filter`** is your friend in need.

> A filter is an object that performs filtering tasks on either the
>   request to a resource (a servlet or static content), or on the
>   response from a resource, or both.
>
> <sub>~ [Filter (Java(TM) EE 7 Specification
>   APIs)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) ~</sub>

---

Read more,

- [Servlet Filter - javatpoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/servlet-filter)
- [Filtering Requests and Responses - The Java EE 6 Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html)
- [Authentication and Authorization with Filter in JSP-Servlet - YouTube](https://youtu.be/t9CPWIm_F-Y)